# django-import-export get resource field not present in model

Tags: python, django, import, django-import-export

According [django-import-export Docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#declaring-fields) we can add fields to Resource that they are not present in target model. So, I have next Resource:

```
class FamilyResource(resources.ModelResource):
  code = fields.Field(attribute='code', widget=widgets.CharWidget())
  parent = fields.Field()

  class Meta:
    model = Family
    import_id_fields = ('code', )
    fields = ('code', 'name', 'image', )
```

field *parent* is the field it is not present in the related model and I'd like to know how should I do to get the parent value under *save_instance* hook because my *save_instance* logic depends on *parent* value.